# Is there a way in Python to compare variable names with file names in a case insensitive way?

Tags: python, django, performance

I have a function called `get_book` which opens requested book by its `title` argument. Function `get_book` can receive `title` in any case (e.g. `Foo`,`FOO`,`fOo`). While this is not a problem in itself, book folder where the function retrieves a book if the `title`'s are matching, also has book `title`s in a mixed case way. The database folder is dynamic and continuous to receive new book file names (like e.g. `Foo.pdf`,`FOO.pdf`,`FOo.pdf`).

My question is how can I compare `title`s and followingly retrieve requested book without changing file names in the database?  Is there an efficient way to open files without worrying about case matching?

**my code:**

```
def get_book(title):
    """
    Retrieves a book by its title. If no such
    book exists, the function returns None.
    """
    try:
        f = default_storage.open(f"books/{title}.pdf")
        return f.read().decode("utf-8")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return None
```

Comment: Common approach is to convert both sides of the comparison to either lower or upper case: `if s1.lower() == s2.lower():`  Note that both s1 and s2 themselves remain unchanged.

Comment: So, you could get a list of all the file names in the directory, then try to match in a case-insensitive way

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Does this mean I need to use `os.listdir('books')` and run a for loop over all the book titles to use an approach like `if s1.lower() == s2.lower():` ? @Ronald @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: There might be another solution. First, correct me if I'm wrong, but verify if this is what you need: User provides a `title` and you want to find the corresponding file regardless of upper and lower case?

Comment: Yes that`s correct . I couldn't find a way to make 'default_storage.open' ignore the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with an empty `lower_to_name` dict.
Probe it like this, for each new title:

```
title = title.lower() + ".pdf"
title = lower_to_name.get(title, title)
```

Upon getting `FileNotFoundError` for a title,
do a single retry using [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) to lookup actual filename:

```
lower_to_name = {name.lower(): name
                 for name in glob.glob("*.pdf")}
title = lower_to_name.get(title, "no_such_file")
```

(You may find that `os.chdir("books/")` is convenient.)

Answer (score 0):

For finding a case-insensitive file name, [fnmatch](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/fnmatch.html) is a good method.

This example is almost literally the example in the documentation:

```
import fnmatch
import os

title = 'tEst.txt'                    # Try several combinations of upper and lower case
for file in os.listdir('.'):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, title):  # They will be all found here
        print(file)
```